# .htaccess redirect request not index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a setup like this *http://www.example.com/reroute/index.php*.
I would like to send all request not to *index.php* to *index.php*. So anything to */reroute/products* would go to */reroute/index.php* and would display *http://www.example.com/reroute* to the browser.  It seems simple enough but every thing I have tried either tells me file doesn't exist or sends me in a loop.

Also, is it possible to set custom headers before I reroute?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*

# Turn on the RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{IS_SUBREQ} false
RewriteRule ^/index\.php$ http://www.example.com/reroute [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule !^index\.php$ index.php [L]
```

This will rewrite all requests not requesting *index.php* to *index.php* within the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it.

```
RewriteRule ^/reroute/products/$ reroute/index.html [QSA,L]
```

That sends pretty much everything to the index file.